# Запись в сокет выдает ошибку: socket_write(): unable to write to socket 10053. Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, openserver

Пытаюсь реализовать и разобраться с работой сокетов на примере примитивного чата.
Написал сервер, скрипт, класс с методами, однако при попытке запустить - возникли проблемы.
В интернетах говорят лечить выключением антивирусов, однако данные на пк отсутствуют.
Работаю на локальной машине - openserver, при запуске сервера - происходит данная ошибка. В логах она звучит примерно так:

*[09-Jun-2021 21:32:19 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  socket_write(): unable to write to socket [10053]: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение.
in F:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\chatEd\class\chat.php on line 25*
[image: Скриншот консоли из openserver]

Файл server.php

```
<?php
define('PORT', "8090");
require_once "class/chat.php";

$chat = new Chat();

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, PORT);

socket_listen($socket);

while(true) {
$newSocket=socket_accept($socket);
$header=socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
$chat->sendHeaders($header, $newSocket, 'localhost/chatEd', PORT);
}

socket_close($socket);
```

Файл chat.php

```
<?php

class Chat{
    public function sendHeaders($headersText, $newSocket, $host, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $tmp=preg_split("/\r\n/", $headersText);

        foreach ($tmp as $line)
        {
$line = rtrim($line);
if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
{
$headers[$matches[1]]=$matches[2];
}
$key=$headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
$sKey=base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));

$str_back = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols \r\n" .
"Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/chatEd/server.php\r\n" .
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$sKey\r\n\r\n";

socket_write($newSocket, $str_back, strlen($str_back));

        }
    }
}
```

Подключение с помощью jQuery: (файл script.js)

```
function message (text) {
    jQuery('#chat-result').append(text);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090/chatEd/server.php");
    socket.onopen = function () {
        message("<div>Connection succes</div>");
    };
    socket.onerror = function (error) {
        message("<div>Connection failed: " + error.message +"</div>");
    }
    socket.onclose = function () {
        message("<div>Connection closed</div>")
    }
    socket.onmessage=function (event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    message("<div> + data.type + " - " + data.message</div>")
    }
});
```

Comment: посмотрите, как работает Ваш сервер. Он ждет новое подключение, читает с него данные, отправляет назад что то, и сразу ждет новое подключение. А старый сокет теряется. И он закрывается. Но вот клиент не ожидает такого подвоха и кричит об ошибке. Что делать? возможно, в сервере должен быть ещё один цикл для чтения данных от клиента

Comment: Не совсем понимаю из-за чего теряется старый сокет, на сервере реализован бесконечный цикл, в котором не предусмотрена какая-либо потеря сокета. Буду очень признателен если Вы укажете на ошибку в коде.

Comment: из за того, что Вы туда записывайте новый строкой $newSocket=socket_accept($socket);

Comment: Но эта строка как раз и принимает сокет, который посылает нам клиент, и если ее удалить, то потеряется возможность принимать данные, с последующим чтением.

Comment: так Вы как раз этого и не делаете. Вы получили соединение, прочитали, записали и все, цикл по новой. Похоже, что 2 и 3 строки цикла нужно в свой цикл завернуть, до розрыва соединения.

Comment: Вы были правы по поводу потери старого сокета из-за нового подключения, однако ошибка оказалось совсем тривиальной и глупой. В файле chat.php в блоке foreach скобка была поставлена не в том месте, из-за чего запись происходила по 3-4 раза и сервер ложился. Спасибо за потраченное время